# downcasting dynamic_cast with non-polymorphic classes, why doesn't it compile?

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-cast, downcast

I have the following code:

```
using namespace std;

class BaseOk
{
public:
    virtual void ImplementMe()
    {
    };
};
class DerivedOk : public BaseOk
{
public:
    void ImplementMe()
    {
    }
};

class CBase { };
class CDerived: public CBase { };



int main() 
{ 
    CBase b; CBase* pb;
    CDerived d; CDerived* pd;

    pb = dynamic_cast<CBase*>(&d);     // ok: derived-to-base
    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(&b);  // wrong: base-to-derived  -> this doesn't compile

    // Polymorphic case

    BaseOk b2; BaseOk* pb2;
    DerivedOk d2; DerivedOk* pd2;

    pb2 = dynamic_cast<BaseOk*>(&d2);     // ok: derived-to-base
    pd2 = dynamic_cast<DerivedOk*>(&b2);  // wrong: base-to-derived -> this returns a NULL pointer

}
```

The line with the pointer "pd" performs a downcast and I agree that it should fail because the result is a totally different object. 
My question is: why doesn't the dynamic_cast in that line compile at all instead of just returning a NULL pointer?

I'm using MSVC2012 compiler

Comment: Post the error message you are getting as well

Comment: dynamic_cat assumes RTTI info and if you have non polymorphic types you don't have either RTTI (try dynamic_cast int to float you will face the same)

Comment: It compiles for me on gcc 4.7.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644753/c-dynamic-cast-polymorphic-requirement-and-downcasting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does dynamic cast from class to subclass requires the class to be polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229381/why-does-dynamic-cast-from-class-to-subclass-requires-the-class-to-be-polymorphi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the `dynamic_cast` in that line compile at all instead of
>   just returning a NULL pointer?

Consider this as a feature/facility rather than a limitation.

`dynamic_cast` is a mechanism where we would find the RTTI (run-time type information) of an object based on the pointer/reference.
Now suppose if a class is not at all polymorphic (i.e. doesn't contain any `virtual` method), then definitely the `dynamic_cast` will **always fail**.
Which means you don't have to use the `dynamic_cast` where there is a 0 probability of passing. *Why should you waste machine cycles on the thing which is known at compile time*? That's why compiler provides you the facility straight away.

There is another hidden advantage of this. Suppose you are using `dynamic_cast` with references, if it fails then an exception is thrown. Would anyone want to handle an exception for something which is already known at compile time!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dynamic_cast` on a pointer to a non-polymorphic type is an error. That's a diagnosable rule, so you should get a compile-time error.

Using it on a pointer to a polymorphic type which is not convertible to the target type is not an error, and in any case is not generally detectable when compiling. It has well-defined behaviour, giving a null pointer.

Comment: `Using dynamic_cast on a pointer to a non-polymorphic type is an error` ... I think "error" is improper word in this context. It's rather a trivially known information which is "always false"; which is informed to the user by a compilation error.